# Puppet agent daemon should not start during startup

Tags: puppet

I have installed puppet agent in my servers.

1.My agent is running automatically and is stopping my apache which is installed via puppet.
puppet agent --configprint runinterval
1800

2.I can kill the process but do not want this process to start during server reboot.

Can someone have any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem.  Do you not know how to use the service management tools for your platform?  Is Puppet starting a boot *despite* you having (you thought) disabled it?  Having the agent installed in no way requires that it start at boot or that it run on any particular schedule.

Comment: I am speaking about puppet runinterval

Comment: Now I *know* I don't understand what the problem is.  Puppet's `runinterval` setting has nothing to do with whether the agent (or the master) starts at boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm. After installing my agent for the first time, I ran it the first time, to request a certificate from master with

```
 sudo puppet agent --verbose --no-daemonize --onetime
```

Which (among other things) instructs the agent to not continue running as a daemon.

Then after signing the cert on master I am able to run the agent on demand with.

```
sudo puppet agent -t
```

The -t (--test) flag on the agent effectively adds --onetime --verbose --no-daemonize --no-usecacheonfailure --detailed-exitcodes --no-splay --show_diff --no-use_cached_catalog to the agent run. Therefore this way the agent is always run --nodaemonize, and I have not run into the problem of the agent running automatically.

Not sure if this addresses your use case.